# Why does Contacts on Mac OS X (10.15.7) use the full power of the CPU?

Tags: macos, cpu-usage, contacts

## Goal

My **goal** is to understand *(i)* why the Contacts application on Mac OS X 10.15.7 continues to use the entire CPU, even after loading all contacts and phone numbers, including a contact that contains 19'000 phone numbers; and *(ii)* what I can do to prevent this from happening, even with a contact that contains 19'000 numbers.

## Situation

With a Python script, I generated a contact file (.vcf). It's a **single contact** that contains about **19'000 phone numbers**. This file respects the [vCard 4.0 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#vCard_4.0). The resulted contact file looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
N:LastName;FirstName;;;
TEL:123456789 # This line is repeated 19'000 times
END:VCARD
```

I imported this contact in the **Contacts** application of **Mac OS X (10.15.7)**. At the time of the import, the entire **CPU** was used for this task (which made sense to me, because the application must integrate 19'000 new numbers).

## Problem

Now, every time I launch the Contacts application, the **entire CPU** is used by it (which makes sense to me the time it takes for the application to generate the preview of the 19'000 numbers).

However, this intensive CPU usage continues **even when all contacts and phone numbers have been loaded** (= even when I can scroll through the 19'000 numbers list). It can take up to 10 minutes to load all contacts and associated phone numbers.

Here is a [screenshot of Activity Monitor for the CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOpZy.png) more than 10 minutes after launching the Contacts application. At this point, I can already scroll through all contacts and phone numbers.

## 2 questions

**(1)** Why does the Contacts application on Mac OS X 10.15.7 continue to use the entire CPU, *even after loading all contacts and phone numbers*?

**(2)** *What can I do to prevent this from happening?* Should I change the format of the .vcf file? What are other (better) ways to import a huge list of phone numbers inside a single contact file?